# click addClass function only works if called on page and not in external js file

Tags: jquery, css, external

I'm sure this is a super noob question, but as a super noob I'm ready for the flack ;)

I'm using the following function to add a class to a clicked element :

```
$(".ch-buyBt").click(function()  {
    var nowincart = $(this);
    nowincart.addClass('ch-buy-incart');
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to store this function in an external js file which holds a bunch of other functions. When I do this, the function no longer works.

The only way I can get it to work is by embedding it on the actual page like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ch-buyBt").click(function()  {
    var nowincart = $(this);
    nowincart.addClass('ch-buy-incart');
});</script>
```

Could somebody please explain why this only works on the page and not when located in the external js file? I imagine that i'm just calling it wrong or something.

Comment: Place it under document.ready. Chances are that your external scripts load before the document has been loaded., and inline script comes after the element in html. Place your external scripts as `$(function(){...Place dom element event regsitry script here...});`

Comment: Did you place the script tag with the external file in the same place where you had the tag with the code?

Comment: @ PSL, ok that makes sense. Let me try that!

@ Musa, i'm not sure what you mean? Can you expand on that?

Comment: @Grant What :@musa is saying is Did you place the script tag for the external js file in the same place where you had the event registration script in the html.

Comment: Ahh I see!  No I was calling it on the page in the footer and the global.js file was being loaded in the head. Totally explains why it was bombing out. Makes perfect sense to me now, thanks so much for explaining it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ch-buyBt").click(function(){
        var nowincart = $(this);
        nowincart.addClass('ch-buy-incart');
    });
});
```

to make sure that the js code is executed after the external js files are loaded.

Comment: Thanks Davidsun, I just tried it like this before you posted that above.. Is this ok too? `$(document).on('click', '.ch-buyBt', function() {
        var nowincart = $(this);
        nowincart.addClass('ch-buy-incart');
});`

Comment: @Grant It will not work in all situations... sometimes the document will be clicked BEFORE all the HTML elements are loaded.